# How to configure a wifi router and a Raspberry Pi for IOT devices

Tags: networking, ipv6

I'm building some IOT devices that I want to be able to access from my local network and possibly from outside my home as well. I want to connect my devices to a Raspberry Pi because my IOT devices cannot communicate directly with my WiFi router. My devices will send and receive IPv6 packets. Here is a diagram to help me explain what I am trying to achieve (with possibly different IPv6 addresses and subnets):

[image: IOT network diagram]

Computer 1, Computer 2, and my Raspberry Pi are all connected to my WiFi router. My IOT devices are connected to the Raspberry Pi through their own interfaces via a hat (802.15.4 radio, serial line, etc.).

My goal is to allow Computer 1 and Computer 2 to access the IOT devices behind the Raspberry Pi. In order to do that, they need to send packets through the WiFi router.

## Question

How can I setup the Raspberry Pi so that it tells my WiFi router about the existence of the network behind the Raspberry Pi? I don't really care what subnet the IOT devices are assigned. I'm just looking for a solution that is relatively straight forward and requires no configuration on the WiFi router. Basically, I just want the Raspberry Pi to act as a dumb link between my IOT devices and the rest of the network.

While I need to get a solution up and running, I'm also interested in the underlying networking standards and stuff. I've been doing some reading of the standards trying to figure things out but it feels like I'm swimming in mud.

Comment: "*My IoT devices are connected to the Raspberry Pi through their own interfaces via a hat (802.15.4 radio, serial line, etc.).*", explain more about this important part, how the IoT devices contract with the raspberry pi? How it assigned the IP?

Comment: I guess that's the next question. I create a TUN interface to bridge between the Raspberry Pi and my hardware. I've got to the point where the my code can read and write to the TUN interface. Then I started trying to send pings through the TUN from another computer which has been unsuccessful.